# WIX: Add custom HTML or my own form (to another website)

Tags: velo

I need to create a form that by clicking on it will redirect to another website with special 'inputs' tags values.

something like:

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="val1" value="something">
  <input type="hidden" name="val2" value="else">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

The custom HTML feature that I find will put it inside an iframe, and it looks bad. Is there a way to do it that will look 'normal'?

Answer (score 2):

If you utilize Wix Code you can develop that inside your Wix page without the need of any html forms.

Simple solution:
- Add the form input elements you need on your page
- Add a button to click on
- Add av event handler to the button and grab the values from the input fields
- Send that data to any site or redirect the user to the site you want using wixLocation.to("url") with the query parameters you might need from the form.